# React tree component with a node open

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a react tree component. I could able to build the react tree. However not able to default expand a node path. Given an id I have to open the whole path from where the nesting start.

```
const TreeView = ({data}) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(item => (
          <TreeNode item={item} key={item.id}/>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

const TreeNode = ({item}) => {
  const [childVisible, setChildVisible] = useState(false);
  const hasChildren = Boolean(item.children);
  const iconClass = classNames({
    iconDown: childVisible
  })
  return (
    <li>
      <div className="flex-class" onClick={() => setChildVisible(old => !old)}>
        {hasChildren &&<div className={iconClass}><FaAngleRight /></div>}
        {item.name}
      </div>
      {
      hasChildren && childVisible && 
        <TreeView data={item.children} />
      }
    </li>
  )
}
```

Let's say I am passing an id to the component, how can I default open that path?

Comment: Usestate(hasChildren || false)

Comment: This is what I did - if your ids are well known - your nodes could subscribe to some publish event (look up a pub/sub util) - trigger an event with a specific id - the node can listen for events on its id and can then toggle, open, or close themselves.

Comment: another way is have a top level action which will walk the tree data , and toggle the specific nodes childVisible (in state - and then setstate). - you might need to force a re-render, as on earlier version of react, nested states didnt re-render for me

Comment: also, you should model this in your tree data - i.e. item.childVisible and set initial/default value

Comment: I want to open the whole path. If an id is specified which is 3 level nested. I want to open this path by default.

Comment: have the data hold the open and close states of your nodes. - toggle this at the top level, using state.  the prop should propagate  - if not - force a re-render.

if you want to do this externally - using events - see pub/sub pattern
e.g.
```https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js```